# Idiomatic way to do conversion/type assertion on multiple return values in Go

Tags: casting, go, return-value

What is the idiomatic way to cast multiple return values in Go?

Can you do it in a single line, or do you need to use temporary variables such as I've done in my example below?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func oneRet() interface{} {
    return "Hello"
}

func twoRet() (interface{}, error) {
    return "Hejsan", nil
}

func main() {
    // With one return value, you can simply do this
    str1 := oneRet().(string)
    fmt.Println("String 1: " + str1)

    // It is not as easy with two return values
    //str2, err := twoRet().(string) // Not possible
    // Do I really have to use a temp variable instead?
    temp, err := twoRet()
    str2 := temp.(string)
    fmt.Println("String 2: " + str2 )


    if err != nil {
        panic("unreachable")
    }   
}
```

By the way, is it called `casting` when it comes to interfaces?

```
i := interface.(int)
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can't do it in a single line.
Your temporary variable approach is the way to go.

> By the way, is it called casting when it comes to interfaces?

It is actually called a [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).
A type <strike>cast</strike> conversion is different:

```
var a int
var b int64

a = 5
b = int64(a)
```

Comment: Actually, that is not called a cast either. It is called a conversion. http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

Answer (score 45):

```
func silly() (interface{}, error) {
    return "silly", nil
}

v, err := silly()
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

s, ok := v.(string)
if !ok {
    // the assertion failed.
}
```

but more likely what you actually want is to use a type switch, like-a-this:

```
switch t := v.(type) {
case string:
    // t is a string
case int :
    // t is an int
default:
    // t is some other type that we didn't name.
}
```

Go is really more about correctness than it is about terseness.

Comment: Still I think Go succeeds in being quite terse as well without giving up correctness. For others who see this question, I think it is good that you mentioned the assertion check. In my case though I already know what type is stored in the interface, so I skipped the check. I even thought about using an `unsafe.Pointer` instead of `interface{}`, but I guessed there is not enough overhead in the type assertion justifying the use of unsafe pointers.

Comment: I should probably point out, that the idiomatic way to do this is to not return interface{}, but to accept interface{} as an input parameter, check the type that was passed in, and then fill that type.  This is exemplified quite nicely in the encoding/json package's Unmarshal method.  These techniques don't cover all the same situations, so it may not always be possible, but it is in general better to accept interface{} than it is to return interface{}.  You can use the reflect package to check to make sure that the provided value is a pointer.

Answer (score 31):

Or just in a single if:

```
if v, ok := value.(migrater); ok {
    v.migrate()
}
```

Go will take care of the cast inside the if clause and let you access the properties of the casted type.

Answer (score 12):

[template.Must](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Must) is the standard library's approach for returning only the first return value in one statement. Could be done similarly for your case:

```
func must(v interface{}, err error) interface{} {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return v
}

// Usage:
str2 := must(twoRet()).(string)
```

By using `must` you basically say that there should never be an error, and if there is, then the program can't (or at least shouldn't) keep operating, and will panic instead.

Comment: It is unidiomatic to panic on errors that were not caused by a programmer. A function like `template.Must()` is normally used for loading templates from a variable in package level declarations and `init()` functions. The idea is to panic immediately at runtime and make it obvious that something the compiler could not catch is wrong. You should not use this to avoid temporary variables.

Comment: And which part of "By using `must` you basically say that there should never be an error" wasn't clear? You shouldn't use this unless the error can only be caused by a programmer or the program really can't continue if there is an error.

Comment: I disagree with "or the program really can't continue if there is an error". In that case you still should not panic.

Comment: It's not even an argument, since I mostly agree with that one. It is only idiomatic if you can't or prefer not to log the error. So it's rarely idiomatic.

Comment: But, in your 1st comment, why did you assume that I said it is idiomatic to panic on errors that were not caused by a programmer?

Comment: While I see Stephen's point, the answer is still useful in some cases (as Stephen also pointed out). Thanks for the wrapper thought.

Comment: Worth mentioning that in tests, must() like writing is _very_ handy.  Gomega has nice shorthand for this: https://onsi.github.io/gomega/#handling-errors.  However if it crashes the test, you need to recover and be careful about cleanup. Gomega has pluggable "fail handler"; Ginkgo provides panic, recovery (https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#marking-specs-as-failed), and `AfterEach`/`AfterSuite` blocks for cleanup.